# Am I getting my message across?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> 1. A solution is hypertonic to a cell if its concentration of
>      non-penetrating solutes is greater than that within the cell.
> 2. A solution is hypertonic to a cell if its concentration of
>      non-penetrating solutes is greater than the concentration of
>      non-penetrating solutes within the cell.

Do these convey the same message?

Comment: Yes, you're conveying the same message.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives this as one of the many definitions of *that*:

> *that, pron.*: Referring to a preceding n., and equivalent to *the* with the n.
>
> e.g. The proportion..between the load at the maximum and that by which the wheel is stopped.

So yes: in your example, *that* is a pronoun equivalent to "the concentration of nonpenetrating solutes". It is grammatical, readable, and equivalent to repeating the noun. I would even call it preferable due to brevity, but that is soley a matter of opinion.

Comment: I think that avoiding the repetition, by using "that", makes the sentence more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be grammatically correct, but the following sounds better:

> A solution is hypertonic to a cell if its concentration of nonpenetrating solutes is greater than **those** *within* the cell.

Comment: No it isn't.  "those" is used when referring to a plural.  The thing being referred to is the **concentration** (which is singular), not the **solutes**.  So *that* is correct.